# “HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found” for a deployed MVC app

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a simplest MVC app. It was built using Visual Studio 2019 for .NET 4.5. It runs OK within the Studio.
I then published the app on the same computer (Server 2012 R2) in IIS 6.2. When I enter http://localhost/mvc2/HelloWorld in a browser I get error message “HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found”.
What could be the reasons of the problem?

Comment: instead of localhost in the url, try the server's name. change http://localhost to http://myserver (whatever the server's name is)

Comment: I have tried  this - no change

Comment: About 404 error, you can refer to the official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-404-file-not-found-error. Also, is the Helloworld html or aspx? You can try accessing for example: http://localhost/mvc2/HelloWorld.html.  IIS 6 has been out of life for a long time and is no longer supported. Please use a supported version of IIS. It cannot be ruled out that this error is caused by the IIS version being too outdated.

Comment: I have chedked out - the IIS versoin is 8.5, not 6; sorry.

"is the Helloworld html or aspx" - no; there is no such file.

Comment: Check whether the file exists in the path, permission issues can also cause 404 error. Try to enable FRT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing to get detailed error information.